# SQL SSIS Package ending at 33%?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis, ssms

So i'm setting up a script to get data from an sql database and output it into an excel file. When creating the ssis package in smss, and i select the option to run immedietly, it works. As soon as i try to execute it from my bat file, It says the following error. I had gotten it to work a few times, but now no matter what i do i cant run this anymore without getting the error. sqlexpress 2019 with smss 2019, office 2016 standard 32bit & both ACE providers 16.0 32x and 64x installed. Any idea's?

```
Progress: 2022-05-19 10:54:28.24
   Source: Data Flow Task 1
   Validating: 0% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2022-05-19 10:54:28.24
   Source: Data Flow Task 1
   Validating: 33% complete
End Progress
```

And then it just stops here... Why does it get to 33% and then stop? The query is correct, When i run the query in smss, it outputs what I need. But here randomly it stopped working.....

Comment: In all probability, it's waiting for some keyboard input. Without seeing the batch code, we'd be guessing. Please edit-in your batch code.

Answer (score 0):

sqlexpress does not support execution of existing SSIS packages. You must have a licensed developer/standard/enterprise instance installed on the machine to run a stored SSIS Package. SQL Express only allows you to create and run a package immediately.

Reference on Express not support https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15#install-integration-services

Further reference about supported scenarios for SSIS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Wrong, there are multiple other ways you can schedule the task VIA Task Scheduler or Cron on linux, and just run the ssis package via DTEXEC in a batch script or powershell. Everything works. Not my first

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, I uninstalled office 2016 from the computer, and it worked.